# How to add all MonoBehaviours of Scene into the List?

Tags: c#, unity

I've read an article [10000 UPDATE() CALLS](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/).
Author uses UpdateManager. It has `Update` method which calls `Update` method in all of other MonoBehaviours of objects. It works faster than calling `Update` method from each MonoBehaviour separately.

This Manager looks like:

```
private ManagedUpdateBehavior[] list;

private void Start() {
    list = GetComponents<ManagedUpdateBehavior>();
}

private void Update() {
    var count = list.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // UpdateMe
        list[i].UpdateMe();
    }
}
```

And every objects now contains component with the code:

```
public class ManagedUpdateBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
    // some variables

    public void UpdateMe() {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

It's okay if 5-6-7-8- objects will be have that component.

But what if I have 100 objects? 1000? 10000?

How to find and add all `ManagedUpdateBehaviors` from all objects of scene? Should I use some recursive method on `On Start`? Cause every object may contain other objects with the script, they may contain the other objects etc...unlimited nesting

Also some objects can be instantiating dynamically...How to add their mono to manager? What is the right way?